# Are Reality Checks in Groups More Effective?

Tags: perception, reference-request, dreams

Reality checks are recommended to train the capability for lucid dreaming. Are there studies on the effectivness of reality checks done together with a partner or within a group of people?

I think they are at least as effective as individual ones, since it shouldn't matter e.g. who switches the light to see whether it's working, but maybe it's more fun in a group. And maybe it is more common to see someone else in dream doing something rather than performing a task yourself...